# Not able to read parameters returned from External API in MVC action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

I have a small requirement but not sure how to go about it.
I am trying to implement a Payment Gateway in one of my web app.

On clicking "MakePayment", the user is redirected to Payment Gateway to enter Card details (Payment Gateway API also expects the SUCCESS and ERROR URL to redirect the user based on the case as it may be.)

Problem is when the user enters incorrect card details, the Payment API returns to the errorPage URL on the web app (passed by me as a parameter while redirecting from the website to the Payment Gateway) and it also returns a ampersand('&') separated parameters like the one below:

paymentid=9436816441510041&ErrorCode=QQ89&ErrorText=Signature
validationerror&udf1=customer@emailid.com&udf2=address1&udf3=address2&amt=1.0

I have created an action with the Error URL and on entering incorrect card details the user is successfully being redirected to this Action, but how to read the params returned???

**Approached tried:**
1) I have tried something like::

```
public ActionResult errorURL(string paymentid, string ErrorCode,... etc)
    {
  // Do something with the Params

        return View();
    }
```

2) I have also tried in the Action Body:

```
Request["trackid"]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use `Request.QueryString["paymentid"]` in the action body

Comment: Thanks. I tried via QueryString but it is returning No Keys. Entire QueryString Parameter in Request object is blank.

Comment: does the redirected url contain a "?" character? otherwise parameters won't be recognized

Comment: Strange. Try `Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]`. Can you see the full url that is sent back to you?

Comment: PaymentAPI reference document has stated not to append anything to Success URL and ErrorURL. May be it append the Parameters automatically to the URL after processing the entered card details by the user. All that they have mentioned is this is the syntax of return parameters('&' separated). Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"] is also coming blank.